# Bootstrap columns aren't nesting properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a simple Advent calendar using Bootstrap ('tis the season).
I'm nesting 7 columns per row for the 7 days of each week.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row title">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><p>Advent Calendar</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row weekdays">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Mon</p></div>
        ...
        <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Sun</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row dates">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><p>30</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"><p>1</p></div>
        ...
        <div class="col-xs-1"><p>6</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [this fidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14714/) for result.

Unfortunately, the total size the columns exploit is 7/12, not 12/12: they aren't using the full width of the viewport.
Isn't bootstrap supposed to take care of proportions? How can I make them use 100% of the width?

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap [v3.0](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.0/docs/css/#overview-container) (like you are in your jsFiddle), `container-fluid` doesn't exist in that version just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this tool for customizing your bootstrap
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

in grid system section you can set 14 for `@grid-columns` instead of 12, then yor customized bootstrap will be 14 columns and then use `col-xs-2` instead of `col-xs-1` in your html code for each day, then you have full page width for your calendar.